# Editing a specific footer column in Word with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to edit the right-hand column of a three-column footer in Word. I am able to edit the entire footer just fine, but I want to leave the first two columns intact.

```vb
Public WithEvents App As Word.Application

Private Sub App_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
     'ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "my value"
End Sub
```

I've seen all sorts of solutions for editing headers and footers, but none that edit only a specific portion of a separated footer.
I'm starting to wonder if the footer is just defined as one big field that can't be distinguished by the left/right separated parts.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Footers don't have columns. Some template creators add a table to the footer to divide it into sections similar to columns.

Comment: You need to determine what is separating the text. The text could be in a table or simply separated by tab characters. Click the Show/Hide button on the Home tab to show non-printing characters.

Comment: I was suspecting as such. Well then, it seems the only way to do what I want would be to identify the seperating characters between these "columns." Unfortunately, this has become another problem in it's own. The "Show Formatting" option shows every indication that these are tab characters with tab stops set to 3.25 and 6.5 respectively, but the search tool doesn't identify them as such. It's as if they're their own unique character, but I have no idea how to identify what they are in order to find them through a search function.

Comment: @ConnorKurschat - when replying to a comment type @ followed by the user name as this will notify them of your comment.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should help you. Just uncomment the relevant block of code for the part of the footer you want to edit

```
Sub EditFooterText(ByVal Doc As Document, NewText As String)
   Dim footerRange As Range
   Dim leftTab As Long, rightTab As Long, footerLength As Long
   Set footerRange = Doc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
   With footerRange
      'find the tabs
      leftTab = InStr(.Text, vbTab)
      rightTab = Len(.Text) - InStrRev(.Text, vbTab)
      
      'to edit the left text
'      .Collapse wdCollapseStart
'      .MoveEnd wdCharacter, leftTab - 1
      
      'to edit the centre text
'      .Collapse wdCollapseStart
'      .Move wdCharacter, leftTab
'      .MoveEnd wdCharacter, rightTab
      
      'to edit the right text
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      .MoveStart wdCharacter, (0 - (rightTab - 1))
      
      .Text = NewText
   End With
End Sub
```

If you are calling this from the `BeforeSave` event you can use the following:

```
Private Sub App_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
     EditFooterText Doc, "my value"
End Sub
```

If the footer is separated with Alignment Tabs, which look identical to a normal tab with Show/Hide turned on but have a different character code, then you can use the routine below:

```
Sub EditFooterTextWithAlignmentTabs(ByVal Doc As Document, NewText As String)
   Dim footerRange As Range
   Dim leftTab As Long, rightTab As Long, footerLength As Long
   Set footerRange = Doc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
   With footerRange
      'find the tabs
      leftTab = InStr(.Text, Chr(48))
      rightTab = Len(.Text) - InStrRev(.Text, Chr(48))
      
      Debug.Print leftTab
      Debug.Print rightTab
      
      'to edit the left text
'      .Collapse wdCollapseStart
'      .MoveEnd wdCharacter, leftTab - 1
      
      'to edit the centre text
'      .Collapse wdCollapseStart
'      .Move wdCharacter, leftTab
'      .MoveEnd wdCharacter, rightTab
      
      'to edit the right text
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      .MoveStart wdCharacter, (0 - (rightTab - 1))
      
      .Text = NewText
   End With
End Sub
```

You can get the unicode value of a selected character by typing `?AscW(Selection.Text)` in the Immediate window